# In Linux, how do I umask differently for files and directories?

Tags: linux, bash, bashrc, umask

I wish to have something in my .bashrc that will mask the file permissions as 022 (resulting in new files having permission rwxr--r--) and the directory permissions as 066 (resulting in new directories having permission rwx--x--x).

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that.  Having a directory with just x allows others (with suitable permissions) to run programs within the directory but not list the contents of it. What are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: Not actually quite correct -- execute permissions on a directory allow access to its contents. A directory set `711` will allow users to enter the directory and view files if they know the name, but won't allow `ls`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it works for me:
http://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-p-6650651.html